# Debugging Python on the BBC micro:bit with Pycharm

Tags: debugging, bbc-microbit, python, pycharm

I am following [this guide](https://mryslab.github.io/pseudo-microbit/install/) which seems to be excllent, except for one litte problem:

When I debug, a breakpoint which I set on the first line is nor reached and the script seems to hang.

[image]

The debugger tabs shows that we are connected:
[image]

as does the console tab:
[image]

The command line shown in the console tab is

> G:_Python\BBC_microbit\demo\venv\Scripts\python.exe "E:\coding\Python\PyCharm Community Edition\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py" --multiproc --qt-support=auto --client 127.0.0.1 --port 12153 --file G:/_Python/BBC_microbit/demo/demo.py

Any idea how I can get it to hit the breakpoint?

Comment: For anyone else who wnats to debug Python on the micro:bit, I managed to get it working with [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=PhonicCanine.micro-bit) Visual Studio Code extension. I would prefer to get Pycharm wokring, as I use it at work, but it's good to have a fall-back